# What is the difference between initializing with implicitly and explicitly?

Tags: c++, new-operator

What is the difference in initializing variables `i` and `j` using the operator `new` and `k` and `l` using the `std::auto_ptr` in the following:

```
void foo() {
    // some code ...
    int* i(new int);
    int* j = new(int);
    // ... more code

    std::auto_ptr<int> k(returnsIntPtr());
    std::auto_ptr<int> l = returnsIntPtr();
    // ... some more code

    //delete i and j
}
```

Edit: To be clear I am interested in the difference in the initialize between `i` and `j` and difference between `k` and `l`. I know the difference using `new` and `auto_ptr`.

Comment: They are both strange. The typical way to do so would be `int* i = new int;`

Comment: @Cyber the redundant parentheses in the `j` initialization will simply be ignored, making it identical in function to yours.

Comment: Yes it will, I just noted that it is a strange notation, it is perfectly valid.

Comment: So other than syntax, no difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new(int)
```

Is equivalent to

```
new int
```

After a look at the grammar in [expr.new],

> *new-expression*: 
>  `::` opt `new` *new-placement<sub>opt</sub>*  ***new-type-id***
>   *new-initializer<sub>opt</sub>* 
>  `::` opt `new` *new-placement<sub>opt</sub>* `(` ***type-id*** `)`
>   *new-initializer<sub>opt</sub>*

the intention is clear: There are types that are not parse-able in the traditional `new type(..)` way.
For instance,

```
auto i = new int(*)(); // Doesn't compile

auto j = new (int(*)()); // ... you guessed it
```

---

The second difference in your declarations, that is, direct-initialization vs copy-initialization, doesn't make a difference for scalars. So those statements are completely equivalent:

```
int* i(0);
int* i = 0;
```

The second one is generally more prefered.

Answer (score 0):

a std::auto_ptr (or unique or shared pointer) is a smart pointer. Its a feature of c++ which makes it possible, that you dont have to care about the destruction of the allocated memory in heap.

at example if you create something with new and dont delete it, you can get huge problems and even cause a crash, the smart pointers take care of this evidence.

If you only wanted to know whats the difference between creating them explicitly or implicitly... there pretty much isn´t a real difference as far as i know.